# SQL AAD Token Based Authentication - Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

Requirement - I am trying to connect to azure SQL DB from a asp.net MVC application and the connection type to azure SQL DB is "token based" and below are the set up done from my end.

a. Created an AAD application( ex : MTSLocal ) with certificate based authentication.

b. Added permission to the above AAD in SQL.

CREATE USER [MTSLocal] FROM external provider;

c.In code level I am trying to get a access token by using Client ID( obtained from step a.) and certificate and the resource I am connecting to is "https://database.windows.net". Please refer the sample code -

```
string authority = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.windows.net/{0}",
                "xxxx.onmicrosoft.com");
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);        
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net", AssertionCert);
            token = result.AccessToken;
```

d. I am able to retrieve the access token but when I am trying to open the SQL connection.I am getting the above said error.

```
        sqlBuilder["Data Source"] = serverName;
        sqlBuilder["Initial Catalog"] = databaseName;
        sqlBuilder["Connect Timeout"] = 30;

        string accesstoken = GetAccessToken();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlBuilder.ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.AccessToken = accesstoken;
                connection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Any help on this would be really helpful.

Comment: without seeing some code and other info about how you're doing this it's not going to be easy for anyone to answer you meaningfully. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance about what to put in your question.

Comment: sorry for that.. I used the code sample from - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862095/acquiring-azure-ad-token-for-azure-sql-server 
But in the connection.open() line of code I am getting above said exception.

 connection.AccessToken = accessToken;// I am able to get the access  token successfully
 connection.Open();

Comment: Please describe your architecture more specifically.  Client, Azure DC, SQL server and any web server or other type of application server which may be in front of the SQL server.

Comment: please put _your_ code, inside _your_ question. And also information about _your_ setup, as mentioned by the comment above. Ok you took the code from another question, but that question could get deleted or amended in future. For _this_ question to make sense, all the necessary information must be within it. Just to warn you, questions which don't have all the required info _within_ them can legitimately be closed off by the moderators - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for the reasons.

Comment: @T-Heron - I have appended all the details.. Any help would be very helpful.

Comment: The azure SQL DB has the SQL service running under what type of account? Is it running under an AAD account, Local System, Network Service, or Local Service? If it is running under an AAD account, I need the output of the following: setspn -L <AADaccount name>. If it is running under any type of local account, I need the output of the following setspn -L <SQL DB machine name>

Comment: I believe it is running under local account because I haven't configured anything related to AAD. So I took the default name which I gave during the installation and below is the output. Please guide me.

setspn -L MSSQLSERVER
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=MSSQLSERVER,OU=Clusters,OU=Machines,DC=xxx,DC=corp,DC=microsoft,DC=com:
 MSClusterVirtualServer/MSSQLSERVER.xxx.corp.microsoft.com
 MSClusterVirtualServer/MSSQLSERVER
 HOST/MSSQLSERVER.xxx.corp.microsoft.com
  HOST/MSSQLSERVER

Comment: @T-Heron any luck on this?

Comment: Please double-verify SQL service is running under Local System.  Also please use the @ notification to be sure I see your message in future in a timely manner.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the information found. It is hard to read inside a comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Token-based database authentication fails with "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560663/token-based-database-authentication-fails-with-login-failed-for-user-nt-author)

Answer (score 4):

Here is some rough and ready code on how I solved this. I had to supply the host tenant (see  in the code below.

```
    private async Task<string> SqlServerVersion()
    {
        var provider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        var token = await provider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/", "<host tenant>.onmicrosoft.com").ConfigureAwait(false);

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            csb.DataSource = "<your server>.database.windows.net";
            csb.InitialCatalog = "<your database>";
        };

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.AccessToken = token;
            await conn.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT @@VERSION", conn))
            {
                var result = await sqlCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                return result.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Notice how the code in the answer is using ('https://database.windows.net/') instead of ('https://database.windows.net'). This is also important to overcome the Anonymous logon issue. So use - ('https://database.windows.net/'). Yes '/' at the end is important.

Comment: @amol-natu Wow. Adding the trailing / solved my anonymous logon error. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Application Registered in the AAD should be added to the users list of the DB and respective roles should be given to DB USER.

For suppose the name of the App registered is "App_AAD_Register_Name". add this user to the corresponding DB like executing the below query. With this the user will be added to Principal Users list of the DB server.

CREATE USER [App_AAD_Register_Name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER.

Create some generic Role like below

CREATE ROLE [RoleUser]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO [RoleUser]
GO
GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO [RoleUser]
GO

Once Role is created and respective permissions are given, assign the role to the user created in the first step.

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'RoleUser', N'App_AAD_Register_Name'.

Once all these steps are done you will be able to connect to DB with the token.

These steps worked for me.

Comment: I am trying to connect from a powershell script in Azure Automation. I looked up the Azure Automation RunAs user and added them but I still get the same Anonymous Logon error regardless. Every other guide I've read says that you need to add the service principal to a windows group then add the windows group to the SQL Azure database

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and allowed me to use a certificate to authenticate. The other solution did too (on my dev pc), but did not give me any way to control what credentials were used.