# Token-based database authentication fails with "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'."

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory, adal

I'm having trouble getting token-based database authentication working. Connecting with Active Directory Password works, but when connecting with a token I receive the following error:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

This problem has been discussed [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506897/sql-aad-token-based-authentication-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymo) and [here on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/650cd289-ec7c-4108-a608-6476c4e97291/connecting-to-azure-sql-using-aad-access-token?forum=ssdsgetstarted), but no solution is available. [This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/09/28/examples-of-some-connection-errors-for-azure-active-directory-authentication/) suggests there is something wrong with user permissions, but it's rather vague.

## Configuration

Acquiring a token succeeds, with the following method:

```cs
static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
{
    var certificateSDN = "redacted";
    var tenantId = "redacted";
    var clientId = "redacted";
    var resource = "https://database.windows.net";

    X509Certificate2 certificate;
    using (var certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
    {
        certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        certificate = certificateStore.Certificates
            .Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, certificateSDN, false)
            [0];
    }

    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}");
    var clientAssertionCertificate = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, certificate);
    var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientAssertionCertificate);

    return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
}
```

Connecting to the database is done like this:

```cs
var connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
{
    DataSource = "redacted.database.windows.net",
    InitialCatalog = "redacted",
};
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString))
{
    sqlConnection.AccessToken = accessToken;
    sqlConnection.Open();
}
```

The error occurs when calling `sqlConnection.Open()`.

The `clientId` matches the application ID of an app registration. I've created a user in the database, matching the name of the app registration, with the following query:

```sql
create user [redacted] from external provider
go
exec sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'redacted'
exec sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'redacted'
```

## Diagnostics

With the following queries, I check that the user has the roles and has permission to connect to the database:

```sql
declare @user nvarchar(max);
set @user = 'redacted'

select
    u.name
    ,r.name
from
    sys.database_role_members as m
    inner join sys.database_principals as r on m.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
    inner join sys.database_principals as u on u.principal_id = m.member_principal_id
where
    u.name = @user;

select
    class_desc
    ,major_id
    ,permission_name
    ,state_desc
from
    sys.database_permissions
where
    grantee_principal_id = user_id(@user);
```

This is the output:

```
redacted    db_datareader
redacted    db_datawriter

DATABASE    0   CONNECT GRANT
```

Trying to connect with a bogus token gives the same error. So I don't know if there's something wrong with my token, or if there's something wrong with the database configuration. What other diagnostics can I perform, to find the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turned out to be a very minor mistake: `resource` needs a final slash at the end.

So instead of

```cs
var resource = "https://database.windows.net";
```

it needs to be

```cs
var resource = "https://database.windows.net/";
```

Comment: Off by one [character] errors...drive me nuts.  Thank you for this; it fixed my problem as well